# Using absolute paths in django templates

Tags: html, django

Recently I've been working on a project in Django that uses a site-wide CSS layout, so I decided that each template (in this case a template in /projects/index.html) used would extend a base file containing the header, footer, javascript, etc. called `base.html`.

The problem is that my directory structure looks like so:

```
.
├── static
│   └── base.html
├── templates
│   └── projects
│   └── index.html
```

And, as you can see the base file I want to extend is in a higher directory than that of the index.html file. Normally, I would use a relative path and use the following code at the top of the index file: `{% extends "../base.html" %}` or simply use an absolute path to the file (if necessary)

It seems, however, that by using either of these methods, whatever is inside the quotes for extends simply gets appended onto the current path, and my call to the upper directory with .. gets ignored entirely.

That is, if the current path is, for example, `/project/templates/projects` and I use `{% extends "/project/static/base.html" %}`, that will be appended to the current path, causing the system to look for `/project/templates/projects/project/static/base.html`, which, of course, doesn't exist. After researching I came across an article that said the blocking of relative paths is intentional for security purposes, but it leaves me with no way to access any file outside the current working directory.

I figured this had to be an extremely common setup when building a website, and so there must be some sort of way to interact with multiple templates that I'm just not aware of yet. If anyone has any information on that, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your html templates should live under the `templates` directory (including your base.html). The location of this folder is set using the [`TEMPLATE_DIRECTORY`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loading-templates) settings in your `settings.py`. The `static` folder is solely for css, js, etc.

When inheriting from another template using the [`extends`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#extends) tag, the path you give is always relative to your template directory, not project.

Comment: What I had no idea of was the fact that extends is relative to the template directory, that's what's been making my life so hard all day! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your `base.html` should be residing in a `templates` directory and not in the `static` directory.

This is because you define where django searches for templates using the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in your `settings.py` file.  Here, I give an example which computes your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` value dynamically.

```
import os

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'templates'),
)
```

In additional, you need to be aware that django depends on another `setting` called `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` to determine the priority in which it loads up your html files/templates, while searching through your `templates` directories.

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    # 'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
```

Once your `base.html` is located in your `templates` directory, all you need to do in your html files is to write:-

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

and you would extend correctly

Comment: Thank you. I have actually been doing the dynamic directory assignment, I just was not aware that extends is relative to that. I was thinking I might have to write a custom template loader to fix this and was hoping against it, but this seemed like such common practice it would be silly to need to do that.